# What font does windows use for the contextmenu?

Tags: javascript, windows, fonts, contextmenu

I want to create an own contextMenu with JavaScript and keep as close to the contextMenu's the user usually gets. But the default font is nowhere to find.

I tried to google it, but i didn't found anything concerning the font. I also tried the default font from visual studio.

I would like to know how to get the users default font in contextMenu. Otherwise what windows' default font is in contextMenu.

Comment: Windows, you mean Microsoft Windows? Different version & different locale of Windows has different default font.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it.

Comment: I guess the font depends on the version, but I might be wrong since I don't use Windows.

Comment: @Shivan, I mean Microsoft Windows.

Comment: There's no such default font which you could rely on, user can change the used font when ever he wants.

Comment: @Teemu, do you know where this font is saved and is it possible to get it into my javascript?

Comment: The font name is probably stored in some system file (or even registry?), you can't access it with JS.

Comment: My conclusion would be to use an own font, because it is impossible to get the exact font.

Comment: its probably better for the user if your app looks the same on all devices anyway...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're writing an HTML (web) page, and want to pop up a context menu which looks like a context menu from the Windows (XP/Vista/7/8) operating system. Correct?

If so, try to use the font-family '[MS Shell Dlg 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'. This is a pseudo-font-name that will automatically get translated to the font that's currently being used for UI dialogs (and menus).

Mind you, it could very well be that the user is using a theme that uses a different font, or has manually selected a different font; there is no way to determine that from a web page.

Comment: according to your link, since win2k, "MS Shell Dlg 2 simply uses the Tahoma font regardless of language". so use tahoma, which also appears just fine on mac devices. then again, win7+ uses segoe ui according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe#Segoe_UI, so you might want to sniff the OS to be sure.

Comment: @dandavis: you're right; I just pasted in the link based on what I remembered (it's years since I last read it), and I seem to remember something different than what the article says. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a Typography site, Fonts for Windows:

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fontinfo/en/

which explains in details which version uses which fonts.